# How to hook the OS X dictionary

Tags: macos, cocoa, dictionary

on osx lion, you can control-command-d or triple-tap on a word that your mouse is pointed to in any app to launch a popover dictionary. i want to make an app to track the words a user is looking up in the dictionary.

how do i observe the event where the user does control-command-d or triple-tap to launch the popover dictionary?

I understand that the specific API for this is [HIDictionaryWindowShow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/DictionaryServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use **popoverDidShow:**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSNotificationCenter* notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(popoverDidShow:)
                            name:NSPopoverDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

// dictionary is shown or another NSPopover
- (void)popoverDidShow:(NSNotification*)notify { 
    //your code
}
```

Comment: good idea. but how would you know if the popover was from HIDictionaryWindowShow? I mean it could be just another popover anywhere else all over the system.

Comment: Use the **name** method to find out what kind of notification you are dealing with when you receive a notification, `[notify name]` .
 Use the infos in the NSDictionary `[notify userInfo]` .
   Use the **object** associated with the notification `[notify object]` to know the `description, attributeKeys` or others methods