# Cocoa notifications for defining a word

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications

I'd like to subscribe to notifications for when a user defines a word. In OS X, you can define a word using a multi-finger gesture with your mouse over the desired word.  Is there an event I can listen for that will be dispatched when the user defines a word using this gesture? Applications like BetterTouchTool allow you to change this gesture, so there must be some public, exposed API I can't find.

I'm having a hard time finding the right "keywords" for this query in Google.  A lot of what I'm getting back has to do with NSDictionaries.

Cheers,

Comment: you should start with: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SpellCheck/SpellCheck.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000092i

Comment: And so I shall. Thanks for pointing me in a direction that's somewhat relevant.  Cheers, mate!

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find any notifications related to defining a word; however, the keyword I was looking for is "Dictionary Service".

The documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/DictionaryServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/HIDictionaryWindowShow discusses how to display a dictionary from selecting a word. This is certainly a starting point for those interested in doing something similar.

Edit: Found my answer on another post: [How to hook the OS X dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214768/how-to-hook-the-os-x-dictionary)